# fromEvent giving "ERROR TypeError: Invalid event target" in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular13

I need to have a fromEvent to have a debounce time for a keyup event (keyup event calls an API each time). Below is my relevant code part.

```
@ViewChild('emailInput', { static: true }) emailInput: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('usernameInput', { static: true }) usernameInput: ElementRef;

ngOnInit(): void {
       
        this.initializeUserForm();
        
        this.loadDependentData();

        fromEvent(this.emailInput.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
                filter(Boolean),
                debounceTime(1000),
                distinctUntilChanged(),
            ).subscribe(data => {
                this.validateEmail(this.emailInput.nativeElement.value);
        });

}

public validateEmail(userEmail: string) {
   //method body
}
```

But the above implementation gives the below error.

```
ERROR TypeError: Invalid event target
    setupSubscription http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:23483
    fromEvent http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:23457
    _trySubscribe http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:22048
    subscribe http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:22034 ........
```

I have implemented the fromEvent inside **ngAfterViewInit()** lifecycle hook also. But none of them work for me. Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: used ngAfterViewInit() as mentioned, but not working

Comment: which angular version you're using ?

Comment: I am using Angular 13

Comment: Is ur EmailInput rendering conditionally from UI?

Comment: I think you need to check if nativeElement is not null or undefined. It shouldn't be in ngAfterViewInit. Unless their rendering is conditional.

Comment: Just a question, did you consider using reactive forms? Reactive forms also provide a build in email validator

Comment: Definitely sounds like you could solve all your problems using [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) :) If you insist on this approach, a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably on [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com), would be nice.

Comment: yes i have used reactive forms. Also checked if nativeElement is not null or undefined. but none of them worked.

Comment: use the formControl ValueChanges.